# shunt into the shadows

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> The Muslim conquests completed Europe's **shunt into the shadows** that had begun with the invasions of the Goths, Huns and others two centuries earlier.

"Shunt" reads in Merriam Webster's  dictionary:

> a means or mechanism for turning or thrusting aside

What does "shunt" mean in the above context?

Comment: What part don't you understand? Europe was thrust aside into the shadows (figuratively) by first the invasions of the Goths, Huns and others, and then 200 years later, the Muslim conquests.

Comment: @Mankak did I answer your question properly?

Comment: Source of quote, please!

Answer (score 1):

This word "shunt" in the dictionary means the below as a verb

> direct or divert to a less important place or position

Therefore, in the context above, it probably reveals how the Muslims have forced Europe into hiding/away from capitol/diverted away e.g.

Comment: somewhat figurative expression, I think.

Comment: Oxford Languages actually says "_Perhaps_ from _shun_". Another of the definitions they give is _direct or divert to a less important place or position_, which seems to fit the bill here.

Answer (score 1):

M-W's definition isn't very good in this case. Instead of being "a means or mechanism for turning or thrusting aside", here a shunt is really the act of turning or being thrust aside. [AHD's definition](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shunt) is more appropriate:

> 1. The act or process of turning aside or moving to an alternate course.